# Django y django rest framework, tipo de autenticación para usarlo con react, vue o angular

Tags: django, rest, djangorestframework, autenticación

Tengo unos modelos sencillos y a traves de DRF estoy creando una api:

Tengo la duda de que tipo de autenticación se debe implementar para poder usarlo con angular, vue o react.

Mis dudas serían las siguientes:

**a)** Cómo debo implementar la autenticación para su uso(para usarlo con react, angular o vue), el código python con django me refiero no js?

**b)** Cuando accedo a la url del api creada, el servidor muestra la interfaz navegable de DRF, como puedo hacer para que solo sirva el json crudo para los usuarios no autenticados, la versión navegable del api solo lo deberían ver las personas de desarrollo, como hago esto?

En mi archivo `settings.py` tengo esto:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    )
}
```

El archivo `serializers.py` tengo esto:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from blog import models

class ComentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Comentario
        fields = ('nombre', 'email', 'mensaje')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comentarios = ComentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    full_autor = serializers.SerializerMethodField()                                                              

    def get_full_autor(self, obj):                                                                                                  
        return {
            'nombre': obj.autor.first_name,
            'apellido': obj.autor.last_name
        }
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = (
            'full_autor','titulo', 'contenido', 'creado_el', 'publicado_el', 'status', 'comentarios'
        )
```

No se si se precisa más información.
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

**A)** Si estás desarrollando una API Rest (lo que asumo dado que mencionas DRF) lo que se estila es autenticación a través de tokens. Recuerda que en esos casos el frondend y backend quedan muy diferenciados y la única forma de comunicación es a través del endpoint de tu API, tanto Angular, Vue y React están preparados para consumir estos servicios así que no deberías tener problemas.

La autenticación en servicios Rest son muy variados:

1. Autenticación HTTP básica.
2. Oauth 1 y 2
3. Tokens (lo que está de moda actualmente, especialmente usando [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/))

Para más información al respecto te recomiendo echar un vistazo a este [enlace](https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/tfg/2016/tfg_48974/TFGArticulo_AlexDuran.pdf).

---

**B)** Si deseas retirar la documentación de tu API que genera DRF solo debes retirar una línea similar a la siguiente de tu archivo `urls.py`:

> url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
>   namespace='rest_framework'))

---

Para complementar si deseas saber como consumir un servicio hecho con DRF en Angular tengo un repositorio con lo elemental: [Enlace.](https://github.com/deoxyseia/django-restframework-angular2)

Además agrego un enlace con un ejemplo básico usando JWT: [Enlace.](https://www.octobot.io/blog/2016-11-11-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-in-a-djangoangularjs-web-app/)

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Citando la documentación oficial "API chooses the content type of the response based on the client request". Es decir en el cliente manda el content type. Cuando haces ajax normal pues te regresa el json y normal entras como usuarios

Para ponerle seguridad deberias usar algo como esto a los objetos

```
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                  IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

Para la seguridad puedes usar SessionAuthentication y BasicAuthentication. Eso permitirá auth con password y con sesión.

Checa : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#customizing

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-login-to-the-browsable-api